# convert oracel query into django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Query:

```
select t1.a, t2.b, t3.c, t2.f from t1 t2 t3 where t1.b=t2.c and t1.c=t3.a and t2.b=t3.c
```

t1, t2, t3, t4 represent tables

a,b,c are values

Comment: Share your models?

Comment: its a oracel query i want to create it as a model and make the query into orm

the sample orm query like this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.